# Document deletion issue in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to delete documents from MarkLogic db using rest call.

Following are Document to be deleted which contains timestamp as part of URI.

`/transdata/metadata/2017-06-0806:09:08`

`/transdata/metadata/2017-06-08T09:50:29.411Z`

POSTMAN showing `200 OK` status when i make rest call using delete but actual deletion not happening.

Comment: Please include detailed information about the REST calls you are making.

Comment: DELETE is idempotent in REST, so if the document doesn't exist or the user doesn't have permission to see the dcument exists, there is no error.  (MarkLogic 9.0-2 is adding an option to get an error if the document doesn't exist.) Anyway, are you able to GET the document with the same user and URI?

Comment: Thank you guys for your reply...now my issue is solved.